# Unresolved external symbol 1 and the difference b/w virtual and pure virtual?

Tags: c++

What could have possibly went wrong with this? And where do we use pure `virtual func() = 0;`? Moreover, is it possible to use different functions under one `virtual` command? I mean like `rotate`, could I write `move()`? Struggling to grasp polymorphism.

```
using namespace std;

class shape
{
public:
    virtual void rotate();
};

class triangle : public shape
{
public:
    void rotate()
    {
        cout << "in triangle";
    }
};

class line : public shape
{
public:
    void rotate()
    {
        cout << "in line";
    }
};

class circle : public shape
{
public:
    void rotate()
    {
        cout << "in circle";
    }
};

int main()
{
    shape s;
    triangle t;
    circle c;
    line l;
    shape* ptr;

    ptr = &s;
    ptr->rotate();
    ptr = &t;
    ptr->rotate();
    ptr = &l;
    ptr->rotate();

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

> ```
> error: LNK 1120: 1 unresolved externals   
> error: LNK 2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void_thiscall shape::rotate(void)"(?rotate@shape@@UAEXXZ)
> ```

Comment: Also, you can't create an instance of an object with a pure virtual function.

Answer (score 1):

If you want use "cout" you have to include `<iostream>` header file.

The virtual pure function is an interface, so you can not instance a derived class without implementing it in the derived class.

you have to implement the rotate function in the base class

This code work:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class shape
{
public:

virtual void rotate()
{
   cout << "in shape";
}

};

class triangle:public shape
{
public:
void rotate()
{
    cout << "in triangle";
}

};

class line : public shape
{
public:
void rotate()
{
    cout << "in line";
}


};

class circle : public shape
{
public:
void rotate()
{
    cout << "in circle";
}

};

int main()
{
shape s;
triangle t;
circle c;
line l;
shape *ptr;

ptr = &s;
ptr->rotate();
ptr = &t;
ptr->rotate();
ptr = &l;
ptr->rotate();

system("PAUSE");
return 0;

}
```

Comment: i did use it! :/
can you give any simple example?

Comment: I have added your code modified. Please see if it is ok for you

Comment: Please, if is ok for you, do not forget to mark as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you declared the `shape::rotate` method as virtual and not *pure virtual*, the linker is looking for the implementation of `shape::rotate`.

Two solutions exist:
1) Make the `shape::rotate` a **pure** virtual function by appending `= 0`.
2) Create an empty `shape::rotate` function.

Comment: If he makes `rotate()` pure `virtual` he'll still get an error because he's now instantiating an object of an abstract class.

Comment: 1) if i change it to pure virtual rotate () = 0;
it gives an error C2259: 'shape' cannot instantiate abstract class.
2) haven't i created a void type already?

Comment: Remove the definition of `shape s` in your `main` function.  I did not see any function code inside the `shape` class, *only a function declaration*.

Comment: @MuneerKhan 1) When a class has a *pure* virtual method, that class is now abstract and cannot be instantiated. You have to remove `shape s` and `ptr = &s; ptr->rotate()`. 2) `void` does not mean its implementation is empty, it means that the function does not have a `return` statement that returns something from the function.

Comment: @0x499602D2 i got it working. but i still want to know one thing, so basically if i use a virtual function with empty implementation i.e. { // } it will work just fine where as i were to use a pure virtual rotate () = 0; which does not have a body then i cant use that class at all?

Comment: @MuneerKhan The difference between a virtual function and an pure virtual function is that for a virtual function it is *optional* to override the method in derived classes. When a method is not overridden in a derived class, the base class' version is used instead. If a method is *purely* virtual in the base class, then it is **mandatory** for the derived classes to override it. Therefore, the base class is acting as an interface for its derived classes, and it makes little sense for it to be used directly. That's partly the reason why abstract classes cannot instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

In declaration of Shape, use this:

```
virtual void rotate() = 0;
```